# How to add to a specific column in a dataset while using a foreach loop c#

Tags: c#, datagridview, foreach, dataset

I'm trying to add an incrementing time! column to my datagrid view along side the data that is being pulled from the streamreader 'r'; I have the increment working but the time goes between the rows rather than next to them.
The data is being displayed as followed:

15:46:20
91  154 70  309 83  6451

15:46:21
91  154 70  309 83  6451

When I want to get it to be like this:
15:46:21 91 154 70  309 83  6451

```
                while ((r.Peek() != -1))
                {
                    string timeS = "";
                    string delimeter = "\t";
                    string[] Time1;
                    allData = r.ReadLine();
                    timeS = Dtime.ToString();
                    Time1 = timeS.Split(' ');
                    timeS = Time1[1];


                    string[] rows = allData.Split("\r".ToCharArray());

                    foreach (string row in rows)
                    {
                        Dtime = Dtime.AddSeconds(inter);
                        dataset.Tables[tableName].Rows.Add(timeS);
                        string[] items = row.Split(delimeter.ToCharArray());

                        dataset.Tables[tableName].Rows.Add(items);


                    }

                    this.dataGridView1.DataSource = dataset.Tables[0].DefaultView;
                }
```

Cheers!

Comment: well, instead of adding time as a row seperately, why not just add it to the items array?

Comment: Also, you don't appear to be incrementing `timeS`? a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding `timeS` as a new row by itself, you should add it as the first item in your `items` array, and then add the array as a row.

For example:

```
var items = new List<string>{timeS};
items.AddRange(row.Split(delimeter.ToCharArray()));                
dataset.Tables[tableName].Rows.Add(items.ToArray());
```

Comment: Yeah that worked! Got the increment working too. Cheers!

Comment: Another question I would have is how to grab the values from the fourth column and convert it to a double in order to include a decimal place in the output?

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is this:

```
dataset.Tables[tableName].Rows.Add(timeS);
```

Followed by:

```
dataset.Tables[tableName].Rows.Add(items);
```

So that's why there are two rows being added.

There's a nicer way to do this though. It sounds as though you want to dynamically added another column to hold the time value. Is this defined in your data table, or do you add it at run time? Either way, it needs to be there in order to hold the value.

I modified your code above to get the time value into the last position in the item array. It's not pretty at all, and could be simplified dramatically. Here's my code:

```
string timeS = "Time";
string row = "Value1,Value2,Value3";
string delimeter = ",";
string[] items = row.Split(delimeter.ToCharArray());
string[] newItems = new string[items.Length + 1];

items.CopyTo(newItems, 0);
newItems[newItems.Length - 1] = timeS;
```

So now you have an array where the last item is the time value. You can add this into your data table:

```
dataTable.Rows.Add(newItems);
```

I'm sure there's a nicer way to do this, perhaps this will help you get moving in the right direction.